# CheckBox Operation in Spreadsheetgear

Tags: c#, spreadsheetgear

I have a Excel Tamplate in which i have Checkbox placed in it.
I want to do Check uncheck/Checkbox depending on some condition in Spreadsheet Gear.
Checkbox is already available in the Excel Sheet. I am using Spreadsheetgear 2008.
I googled but cant find answer.
Can Comeone please give me any refernce for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the state of a CheckBox one of two ways:

1. Set the CheckBox's IControlFormat.[Value](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.Shapes.IControlFormat~Value.html) property to the desired value.
2. If the CheckBox is linked to a cell (see IControlFormat.[LinkedCell](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.Shapes.IControlFormat~LinkedCell.html)), set the linked cell's value and it should update accordingly.

Example:

```
using SpreadsheetGear;
using SpreadsheetGear.Shapes;

// Open workbook containing the CheckBox
IWorkbook workbook = Factory.GetWorkbook("CheckBox.xls");
// Assume CheckBox is in Sheet1
IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
// CheckBoxes reside within a Shape, so access the shape
Shapes.IShape shape = worksheet.Shapes["Check Box 1"];
// Access the CheckBox directly
Shapes.IControlFormat checkbox = shape.ControlFormat;

// A checkbox’s IControlFormat.Value will be set to 0 if it is unchecked, 
// 1 if it is checked, and 2 if it is in an "indeterminate" state.  
checkbox.Value = 1;

// Assume CheckBox is linked to cell A1 in this worksheet
worksheet.Cells["A1"].Value = true;
```